# How to manually stop Observer when using a sync pipe in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-pipe, angular-observable

let write simple example that increment every 1 sec and user `| sync` to update the template :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-counter',
  templateUrl: '
      </div> {{time | async}}</div>
      <button (click)="stop()"> stop counter</button>'
  })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  counter: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.counter = interval(1000).pipe(
      map(i => `Result ${i}`)
    );
  }

  stop() {
    this.counter.unsubscribe(); // error. no such thing unsubscribe()
  }

  activate() {
   this.counter /// ??? 
  }
}
```

But now the template got the handler for the `Subscription` value with the `unsubscribe` method .

So how can I stop the counter???

And after I stop it there is a way to activate again ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `takeUntil` operator, which will listen on a second `Observable`, and cancel the subscription when it hears an event. For example, in the code below we create a `Subject` called `stop$`. As soon as we emit a value on `stop$`, our subscription ends

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { map, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, Subject, interval } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <div> {{counter | async}}</div>
      <button (click)="stop()"> stop counter</button>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  counter: Observable<any>;
  private stop$ = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.counter = interval(1000).pipe(
      map(i => `Result ${i}`),
      takeUntil(this.stop$)
    );
  }

  stop() {
    this.stop$.next();
  }
}
```

**[Here is  a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkbatb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

In Rx, you get a disposable subscription when you subscribe to any observable:
This is the basic contract of an observable:

```
Observable<T>.subscribe(observer: Observer<T>) : Subscription
```

In your example, `counter` isn't a subscription, it's the observable itself.

If you want to terminate the observable based on an external condition you can use a limiting operator like `takeUntil` or `takeWhile` to complete the observable sequence. When an observable completes or throws an error, all subscriptions are disposed of.

To create a timer which can be triggered externally:

```
let startStop = new Rx.Subject()

let counter = 
    startStop
    .startWith(false)
    .switchMap(v => v ? Rx.Observable.interval(1000) : Rx.Observable.empty())
    .select((_, i) => i) 

counter.subscribe(x => console.log(x)) //print

//start timer
startStop.onNext(true)

//stop timer
startStop.onNext(false)
```

Comment: Ok so in this use case after i shutdown the observer how can I activate it again ?

Comment: Once torn down, all observers are detached - you'll have to get your template to resubscribe. Do you want to simply want to make a timer which you can start/stop at will?

Comment: Well, here's how to create a timer to start and stop at will.

Comment: It's hard to digest, but look interesting. are the timer reset himself after stop->start or continue from the last index? 
how can I make it just hold and not restart every time?

Comment: It does restart from the last index. Try it for yourself.

Comment: I am not found the `select` operator in the documentation and without it the counter restart every time. also it `startStop.onNext(true)` should be `starStop.next(true)`

Comment: I'm answering the question for Rx in general. `select` is  just an alias for `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I try different approach, instead of using `Observer` using `Subject`;

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-counter',
    templateUrl: `
      </div> {{time | async}}</div>
      <button (click)="stop()"> stop counter</button>
    `
  })
  export class MyCounter implements OnInit {
    counter: Subject<any>;
    value = 0;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.counter = new Subject();
      setInterval(_ => {
        this.counter.next( this.value++ );
      },1000);
    }

    stop() {
      this.counter.unsubscribe(); // work now
    }

    activate() {
      this.counter /// ??? 
    }
  }
```